# jquery find child by type

Tags: jquery, pug

i have a table with couple of rows, each row has three columns, the first column has a checkbox, second column has input box and third one is a button, i need to find the each row first then, then base on the checkbox of that row, get the text from the textbox at the same row. but i have problem to find the checkbox and inputbox,

my jade page is:

```
 table.mapping
 tbody
                     tr
                         td
                           input.checkbox(class='action', type='checkbox',name='event_name')
                                &nbsp;&nbsp; Name
                         td
                                input.vendor-name.input(type='text')
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                         td
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                input(id='filePath', type='file')
                                span.fileLocation
```

my jquery code:

```
rows = $(@el).find('.mapping tbody tr')
for row in rows
  checkbox = row.find('td input.checkbox')  <-- complained here:undefined is not a function
  if (checkbox.checked)
    name = row.find('td input')
```

i also tried row.find('.checkbox') , it didn't work either. anyone can help? thanks!

Comment: Don’t use a `for in` loop to loop through a jQuery selector result, use `.each()`.

Comment: change checkbox = row.find('td input.checkbox') to checkbox = row.find('td input:checkbox')

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an actual `for in` loop, you're iterating over the properties of the `jQuery` object returned rather than the elements within the jQuery array-like object.

Instead, you should use `$(@el).find('.mapping tbody tr').each(function(idx, el) { ... })` and handle your logic in there referencing `$(this)`.

```
checkbox = $(this).find('td input.checkbox');
if (checkbox.checked)
    name = row.find('td input')
```